# Question on hold to closed: exist a time?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I wanted to know the following: since I had the opportunity to close, open, etc... questions I happened to see the words **[on hold]** and **[closed]** (for old answers).

When does a question that is transformed from **[on hold]** to **[closed]**?

Is there a length of time for a question or answer to go from hold to close?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions explains the difference

> Questions are marked `[on hold]` for the first five days after closure to encourage edits and improvements to the question. If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked `[on hold]`, it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be considered for reopening. If it is not reopened within five days, the `[on hold]` notice automatically changes to `[closed]`. There is functionally no difference between an `[on hold]` question and a `[closed]` one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but they both allow comments, votes and edits.

So yes, there is a time period of five days where a recently closed question is *on hold*, it will only be marked as *closed* after that. But there is no functional difference between the two states.

You can find more about the background behind `[on hold]` vs `[closed]` in [Every "close" has its thorn: replace "close" with "on hold" for the first five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497). The only reason behind this transition between the two states seems to be the hope to avoid the psychological effect that *closed* has compared to the more 'temporary' and supposedly friendlier *on hold*.

Comment: Thank you very much...always also for your cordiality.

Comment: @Sebastiano moewe is an example, a source of inspiration and life skills.

Comment: @AndréC Dear colleague, I absolutely agree with you.